# How to display a bootstrap popup, if his position is relative to his parent and the popup is not visible?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I used:

```
<button id="kill-btn"
        data-ng-if="entry.allowStopExecution"
        data-tooltip="{{'272'|i18n}}"
</button>
```

Popup is not visible, because his normal position (top) is outside the container, which must have overflow: hidden. How can I solve this issue?
Thanks.
[Click to view the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LriKI.jpg)

Comment: fix the button code - missing `>`

Comment: Hi. I copy only the essential part of code. The button have more parameters. Everything work perfect, taking in consideration syntax, but this is a CSS problem.

Comment: PLs, could you provide some more code, so we could reproduce an issue.